# I cant delete data from my Mean stack app

Tags: node.js, express, mlab

my create, read, update operations are working except the delete operation and using post-man it gives me the same error. I'm using mlab to store my data

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Student = require('../models/student');


const db = 'mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds036577.mlab.com:36577/andela';
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(db, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error' + err);
  }
});

router.delete('student/:id', function (req, res) {
  console.log('Deleting a student');
  Student.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function (err, deletedStudent) {
    if (err) {
      res.send('Error Deleting Data');
    } else {
      res.json(deletedStudent);
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Error from postman

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>Cannot DELETE /api/students/59fcc17a8a076e216057e116</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Error from the console

core.es5.js:1020 ERROR 
Response
headers
:
Headers {_headers: Map(7), _normalizedNames: Map(7)}
ok
:
false
status
:
404
statusText
:
"Not Found"
type
:
2
url
:
"http://localhost:3000/api/student/5a04b50e2732c630205aec09"
_body
:
"↵↵↵↵Error↵↵↵

```
Cannot DELETE /api/student/5a04b50e2732c630205aec09
```

↵↵↵"
**proto**
:
Body

the code for the other operations are similar and i dont just understand why its not working. Ive been trying to debug for days.

```js
router.get('/students', function (req, res) {
  console.log('Request for all students');
  Student.find({}).exec(function (err, students) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error getting Data')
    } else{
      res.json(students);
    }
  });
});

router.get('/students/:id', function (req, res) {
  console.log('Request for a student');
  Student.findById(req.params.id).exec(function (err, student) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error getting Data')
    } else{
      res.json(student);
    }
  });
});

router.post('/student', function (req, res) {
  console.log('add a new student');
  var newStudent = new Student();
  newStudent.FullName = req.body.FullName;
  newStudent.ImageUrl = req.body.ImageUrl;
  newStudent.CourseOfStudy = req.body.CourseOfStudy;
  newStudent.YearOfEntry = req.body.YearOfEntry;
  newStudent.DurationOfStudy = req.body.DurationOfStudy;
  newStudent.CurrentLevel = req.body.CurrentLevel;

  // newStudent. expectedYearOfGraduation = req.body.expectedYearOfGraduation;
  newStudent.save(function (err, insertedStudent) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error saving student');
    } else {
      res.json(insertedStudent);
    }
  })
});


router.put('/student/:id', function (req, res) {
  console.log('Update the data');
  Student.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,
    {
      $set: {
        FullName : req.body.FullName,
        ImageUrl : req.body.ImageUrl,
        CourseOfStudy : req.body.CourseOfStudy,
        YearOfEntry : req.body.YearOfEntry,
        DurationOfStudy : req.body.DurationOfStudy,
        CurrentLevel : req.body.CurrentLevel}
    },
  {
      new: true
  },
  function (err, updatedStudent) {
    if(err) {
      res.send('Error Updating Video');
    } else {
      res.json(updatedStudent);
    }
  }
  )

});
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>Cannot DELETE /api/students/59fcc17a8a076e216057e116</pre>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: No I mean like, you have `if (err) {` in your code. What happens if you `console.log(err)`? The error you're showing me is just the API error, not the mongo error. Also, please post the error in the question itself, not in the comments.

Comment: Can you show the code for your other routes? Hard to tell what the difference is.

Comment: Off-hand one thing I notice is that your Postman error has `students` (plural), and your route in the code has `student` (singular).

Comment: yes even if i use Student (singular) it gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

the error was from the route i didnt put the '/' before the students

```js
router.delete('/student/:id', function (req, res) {
  console.log('Deleting a student');
  Student.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function (err, deletedStudent) {
    if (err) {
      res.send('Error Deleting Data');
    } else {
      res.json(deletedStudent);
    }
  });
});
```